# Modify object in for loop (async/await)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, async-await

```
exports.allUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let users = await User.find({})

    console.log(users)
    // [{ role: 'user',
    //   skills: [...],
    //   email: 'first.last@mail.com',
    //   education: [],
    //   createdAt: 2019-04-02T11:17:33.979Z
    // },
    // { role: 'admin',
    //   skills: [...],
    //   email: 'first.lastname@mail.com',
    //   education: [],
    //   createdAt: 2019-04-02T11:17:33.979Z
    // } ]

    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      users[i].bluepages = await bluepagesApi.bluepagesMail(users[i].email)
      users[i].image = await bluepagesApi.profileimage(users[i].email)

      console.log(users[i].bluepages)
      // { 
      //   job: 'Developer',
      //   givenname: 'Tony',
      //   ismanager: 'N',
      //   employeetype: 'P'
      // }
      // { 
      //   job: 'Job Title',
      //   givenname: 'Max',
      //   ismanager: 'N',
      //   employeetype: 'P'
      // }
    }

    console.log(users)
    // [{ role: 'user',
    //   skills: [...],
    //   email: 'first.last@mail.com',
    //   education: [],
    //   createdAt: 2019-04-02T11:17:33.979Z
    // },
    // { role: 'admin',
    //   skills: [...],
    //   email: 'first.lastname@mail.com',
    //   education: [],
    //   createdAt: 2019-04-02T11:17:33.979Z
    // } ]

    return res.json({
      users: users
    })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

If I do a `console.log(users[i].bluepages)` inside my `for-loop`the data that is fetched via an API is shown but if I do a `console.log(users[i])` in my `for-loop` the new object is not shown.

Also outside/after my `for-loop` the changes are not visible.

I also tried to do it with `Array.map` without any success.

Node.js logs from my terminal: https://pastebin.com/w7c50YRt

Comment: Do the two methods actually return promises? Also how do you log? Could you show the code with the logs and its output?

Comment: Yes they do @JonasWilms

Comment: I added all console logs and the returned data in my question @JonasWilms

Comment: The `for-loop` executes correctly and the json is sent when the loop has finished.

Comment: Can you print the value of i along with the data? Try using for...of loop.

Comment: @briosheje await works in `for` loop, the way the code is written you'll have to wait for every operation to complete, which is equal to doing `async: false` which is bad practice, but it will work.

Comment: @JonasWilms you're right, tested it right now. Will delete the above. My bad :). Not sure how the above is happening, then! If someone needs to test with async await.. https://es6console.com/jtzrmwpg/

Comment: probably some serialization thing. What is `User` ?

Comment: or, eventually, the array is being altered **somewhere else**?

Comment: I added my terminal logs as a pastebin url to show that the code works and behaves like I described it :)
`User` is a Model from MongoDB/Mongoose!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose tricks you out. It adds a `toJSON()` and a `toString()` method to documents, that only shows the properties defined in the Model. If you log it to the console, `toString` will be called, if you send it as json `toJSON()` will be called.

```
console.log(
  users[0], // looks as if bluepages does not exist
  users[0].bluepages // but it does actually
);
```

To let the users behave as objects, map them to regular objects:

```
let users = (await User.find({})).map(u => u.toObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

mongoose acts according to definition of user schema.
you should add bluepages and image keys to schema of User